# How to conditional format data points on a chart

Tags: excel, graph, charts, tableau-api

So, I am using a combination of Tableau and Excel to create a chart that shows the 2012 presidential election. On the table, i have the cells of the state names show red, if the republican votes > democrat votes, and blue if democrat votes > republican votes. Thing is, as soon as I create a chart, or scatter plot with all the states as data points, they always show one color, and in excel i can only change the color manually, i can't conditionally format the data points on the chart.

How do I make the colors change?

Comment: Can you link a sample workbook?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/results_1 there. I want the state names to show up colored as data points. And if I change the cell values, the colors would automatically change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conditionally format, create a calc field:

```
if [REP Votes] > [DEM Votes] then 'red' else 'blue' end
```

Place this on the color shelf.

I was not sure what type of chart you wanted so I created a few different ones. I think this gets what you're looking for. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/160612%20stack%20question.twbx

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i need. I am using Tableau Public though, any chance you could publish that on tableau public server so that i can edit it from there?

Comment: sure, here you go. https://public.tableau.com/profile/bernardo.roschke#!/vizhome/160612stackquestion/Dashboard1